# How to type routeParams in Angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I have defined routeParam in a RouteConfig:

```
{ path: '/user/:id', name: 'User', component: User }
```

In my code I am calling the router's navigation method:

```
userSelected(userid) {
    this._router.navigate(['User', { id: userid }]);
}
```

The compiler tells me the following:

> Argument of type '(string | { id: any; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string.

How can I type the parameter `id`, so the compiler detects it as a number?

Comment: `{ id: id }` is id passed from a method?

Comment: yep id is a method parameter

Comment: `yourMethod(id:number) {
this._router.navigate(['User', { id: id }]);
}`

Comment: Now it's like this:
`Argument of type '(string | { id: number; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

Comment: @DanielHitzel could you try `userid.toString()`

Comment: what version of angular2 are you using? In 2.0.0-beta.7 router.navigate takes an argument of type any[]. So no type checking should be done. :-/

Comment: yes, I am using 2.0.0-beta.7...

Comment: if you want to transform it to a number you can just use parseInt(userId).

Comment: like @toskv mentioned: From a compilers perceptive, can there actually be type checking?
since the parameter is an array and array only can have one type..

But if so, why is the error thrown anyway?

Comment: @DanielHitzel what matters is that it's an array of any, so anything should go. :) maybe it's not beta.7? I saw beta.8 was released a week ago. Just for completion you can define an array of 2 types. you can do it like this. a: (string | {id: number})[]

Comment: then this sounds more like a TypeScript issue to me..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105848/discussion-between-toskv-and-daniel-hitzel).

Answer (score 1):

I would directly use  this._router.navigateByUrl('user/' + userid );

Comment: you could, but you loose flexibility since you have to hardcode the URL. That method is frowned upon in the documentation as well. :)

Comment: Can you explain what flexibility that will be lost? You will still have the option to use the dynamic user Id. The only hardcoded thing in here, is 'User' [Name] and this is replaced by 'user [path]'. Both are hardcoded :)

Comment: the method he is using gives a semantic name to the path configuration. And he is using that name to refer to the route. He can later change the URL configured with that path without having to change anything else in the application. If you use navigateByUrl and you want to change the '/user' part of the url to '/person' you have to also change the string in all places navigateByUrl is used. :)

Comment: Got it, basically the name does not matter a lot to change, but the path may change. Thanks for your reply :)